# Bluetooth not showing list and not connecting, not turning on

Tags: keyboard, mouse, bluetooth, logitech

I just install Ubuntu and I don't really have much experience with the platform. After installing everything by using regular wired mouse and keyboard, I connected by Logitech wireless mouse and keyboard for normal use after the installation. After the driver were installed I restarted the system. Upon the restart I try to use the wireless mouse and keyboard to put the password and it didn't work, when after login in when i try to connect the but the Bluetooth list doesn't show and it says Bluetooth turned off when i try to turn it on. I am using Ubuntu 20.04.1, AMD Ryzan 7, Aorus x570 Motherboard, the wireless mouse and keyboards are Logitech MX Master and Logitech K780 keyboard.

Comment: Why are you thinking the MB has a BT device?

Comment: I just listed the specs of my computer

Comment: So what is the BT device?